# What is /usr/local/lib on macos?

Tags: macos

> Libgtksourceview-2.0.0.dylib requires version 6001.0.0 or later, but libgio-2.0.0.dylib provides version 5503.0.0

However, I do not know how to raise the `libgio-2.0.0.dylib` version.
What kind of directory is `/usr/local/lib` in the first place?
please tell me.

Comment: When I run command "brew reinstall glib" , the error " No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib " occurred. But libgio-2.0.dylib is not directory. What should I do ? What is rb_file_s_stat ?

Answer (score 8):

All of `/usr/local` is for stuff you (or your system administrator) installed, that did not come with the OS from Apple. `/usr/local/lib` is for libraries: packages of precompiled code implementing various useful functions, that can be loaded and used by apps, but are not themselves apps.

If you don't recall installing these libraries, they were probably installed by an open source software package management system such as Homebrew. Look into using `brew` to upgrade them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW14)

> `/usr` - Contains non-essential command-line binaries, libraries, header
>   files, and other data.

More specifically, `/usr/lib` is for macOS installed shared libraries. Anything under `/usr/local` are user-installed. So `/usr/local/lib` contains shared libraries installed by you.

More likely that not, belongs to the `libgtksourceview-2.0.0.dylib` [gtksourceview installed by Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gtksourceview) and `libgio-2.0.0.dylib` belongs to [glib](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/glib). The error message shows gtksourceview is compiled with a newer version of glib that is available on your system.

There are a couple of solutions, [assuming you have Homebrew installed](https://brew.sh/).

## Reinstall gtksourceview and glib

Reinstall both software

```
brew reinstall glib gtksourceview
```

## Reinstall or upgrade gtksourceview

Either

```
brew upgrade --build-from-source gtksourceview
```

or

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source gtksourceview
```

If the glib dependency is out of data, it will be upgraded too. The `--build-from-source` option will ensure `gtksourceview` is compiled from scratch, linking with the available `glib` version in your system.

Answer (score 0):

For installing a package, you need to compile that package with existing compilers(depends on what language developers used for that package). There are gonna be libraries that compiler needs for installing that package. This is linker's job to link those libraries.

/usr/local/lib is one the directories that linker searches for required libraries. There are  configuration files along with the installation package which search for necessary libraries.